# How to use validator in vue using setup script, typscript and the composition API

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup, vue-validator

I have the following code example from a tutorial and I try to figure out how to use a validator in a similar way as the example, using the script setup, typescript and the composition API.

```
props: {
    image: {
      type: String,
      default: require("@/assets/default-poster.png"),
      validator: propValue => {
        const hasImagesDir = propValue.indexOf("@/assets/") > -1;
        const listOfAvailableExt = [".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png"];
        const isValidExt = listOfAvailableExt.some(ext =>
          propValue.endsWith(ext)
        );
        return hasImagesDir && isValidExt;
      }
    }
  }
```

I know how to declare the type and the default value but I couldn't find a way to use a validator. Is there any function to validate the different properties?

```
interface Props {
  image: string
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  image: require("@/assets/default-poster.png")
});
```

Comment: Did you check the docs? https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#prop-validation . defineProps accepts the same `props` object. It's unknown what is withDefaults in your case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `<script setup>`, only the *function argument* of `defineProps()` supports `validator` (as of Vue 3.2.31). The function argument has the same type as the `props` option:

```js
defineProps({
  image: {
    type: String,
    default: require("@/assets/default-poster.png"),
    validator: (propValue: string) => {
      const hasImagesDir = propValue.indexOf("@/assets/") > -1;
      const listOfAvailableExt = [".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png"];
      const isValidExt = listOfAvailableExt.some(ext =>
        propValue.endsWith(ext)
      );
      return hasImagesDir && isValidExt;
    }
  }
})
```

Note you can't mix the type-only props declaration with the function argument of `defineProps()`, so any other props would also have to be converted into the option form.

Alternatively, you could implement your own prop validation:

```html
<script setup lang="ts">
interface Props {
  image: string
}

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<Props>(), {
  image: require("@/assets/default-poster.png")
});

if (import.meta.env.DEV /* process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' */) {
  const isValidImage = (propValue: string) => {
    const hasImagesDir = propValue.indexOf("@/assets/") > -1;
    const listOfAvailableExt = [".jpeg", ".jpg", ".png"];
    const isValidExt = listOfAvailableExt.some(ext =>
      propValue.endsWith(ext)
    );
    return hasImagesDir && isValidExt;
  }

  if (!isValidImage(props.image)) {
    console.warn(`invalid image: ${props.image}`)
  }
}
</script>
```