# How to validate props? (vue3, composition-api, typescript)

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

How to use **validator** for props value in **typescript**?

```
type Props = {
    name: string
    type?: string // how to use "validator" ?
    modelValue: any
}

const props = defineProps<Props>()
```

How to make it work as in the following declaration:

```
defineProps({
    type: {
        type: String,
        validator(value) {
            return ...
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe [this stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71103028/how-to-use-validator-in-vue-using-setup-script-typscript-and-the-composition-ap) would help you:

but usually, in cases like this, I just go to the [official Vue Discord server](https://discord.com/invite/HBherRA) and ask my questions there to get the best answer from the Vue core team